# Excel If statement giving the wrong results

Tags: excel, if-statement

I am working on a spreadsheet where I need to get the result of a 1, 2 or 3 depending on the conditions in an if statement, however excel is behaving very strangely. I have attached the image below and the IF statement (feel free to advise if the statement can be improved). I wonder if anyone can explain whats going on?

[image: Excel Snap]

The issue I am experience is that The top line, and 3rd line arent different in term of status, no completed date and no revised date. The statement I am running to output 1,2, or 3 is as follows:

```
=IF(AND(K16<>"",J16="",OR(K16<=I16,K16<=J16)),1,IF(AND(K16<>"",J16<>"",K16<=J16,K16>I16),2,IF(AND(K16<>"",J16<>"",K16<=I16),1,IF(AND(K16="",E15="Completed"),1,IF(AND(K16="",OR(E16="Behind Target",E16="Not Started")),3,IF(AND(K16="",E16="On Target"),2,3))))))
```

Can anyone advise please. I am using excel 2003

Comment: I'm sure the If statement could be simplified, but can't tell how.  You're picture has no column letters or row numbers, and the headers are hard to read, all of which makes it even harder to tell what's going on.  Also, you don't say what should cause a 1, 2 or 3 status.  (And those colors make my head hurt!)

Comment: @DougGlancy My apologies, Column K is the "Completed Date", Column J is the "Revised Target Completion Date", Column I is the "Original Target Completion Date". The rows (from top to bottom of the image) are 1-5. In column L (where 1,2,3 should show), the 1's should be for tasks that were completed by the original time or are marked as completed in the status column,

Comment: ..... 2's should be for tasks which have finished after the original target but before the revised target date or are marked as on target but not yet completed, and 3's should be anything are behind target or not started and have nothing in the completed date field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, your formula points to cell `E15` but should probably point to `E16`. That alone may fix your problem. If not, the formula below follows these rules:

- 1's should be for tasks that were completed by the original time or are marked as completed in the status column
- 2's should be for tasks
  which have finished after the original target but before the revised target date or are marked as on target but not yet completed
- 3's
  should be anything are behind target or not started and have nothing in the completed date field

`=IF(OR(E16="Completed",AND(K16<>"",K16<=I16)),1, IF(OR(E16="On Target",AND(K16>I16,K16<J16)),2, IF(AND(K16="",OR(E16="Behind Target",E16="Not Started")),3)))`

Comment: Thanks @Rachel Hettinger :) That worked perfectly. Thanks for your help

Comment: Also I had missed the wrong row, obviously spent too long looing at it and it needed fresh eyes for that :)

Comment: FYI: You can press ``F2`` to highlight the cells that are referenced in a formula. This makes it very easy to spot references that are "out of line". You can also drag the highlighting to move the reference to a different cell.